# Execute python script with import module by bat file

Tags: python

I executed my python script in Spyder and worked without errors but when executed it by batch file the result:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
How we can to execute the python script:
import pandas as pd

by bat file????

Comment: Some more context would increase the chance to a correct solution. Did you maybe write the script in a different environment like anaconda? Could mean that pandas is not installed in your cmd base environment. A (not so clean) solution could be to simply pip install the modules you are missing.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.